# How to find value of computed property of a component from javascript console(chrome/firefox console) in emberjs?

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, ember.js, ember-cli

How can I find the following values in Emberjs from console:

1. Value of **Computed Property of some component**
2. Value of a **Service**

I know it is possible with the use of **`__container__`** but I'm not able to find it in documentation or any other forum.

Since we are not using `ember-data` and are actually using several custom services(e.g. data, ajax, session,...)  this has become essential for us to find some way to get the value of `computed property` and `service` from console.

Comment: Have you tried the ember-inspector? The first is tricky because you may have multiple instances of the component. If you use `ember-export-application-global` the later can be accomplished by something like `MyApp.__container__.lookup('service:myService').get('myProp')`

Comment: Yes, I've tried ember-inspector. However it doesn't show any direct way to get it!

Currently I'm going to container tab in ember-inspector and using Own Properties tab on the right to find out the value of a service. Though this approach seems incorrect :(, i don't know other way to do it.

Comment: You will find `$E` buttons everywhere. If you klick on them you can access that thing in the console as `$E`.

Comment: Can't you just use [log](https://guides.emberjs.com/v2.9.0/templates/development-helpers/#toc_logging) helper in template?

Comment: I can. It's indeed very useful. But there are a lot of them. So, I was searching for a better way.I use console snippets to get data quickly.



@Lux `MyApp.__container__.lookup('service:myService').get('myProp'‌​)` is exactly what I was looking for :) Thanks a lot. Is it documented somewhere? Can I find value of models/controllers/components using this way?